# Search in Action bar not working properly with custom adapter for listview

Tags: android, listview

Well, i am trying to make an activity which will have a listView and will be searchable by the Action bar search option.

If, i use the default arraylist of android, it just works fine.

But when i am trying to use my own adapter which extends baseAdapter, it is not working properly( doesn't search properly).

My total code is in the below link.

[**Link for my App**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzxtkcqv4cu0fg5/MySearchApp.rar?dl=0)

Can someone please help me regarding the issue?

**The codes are::**

Manifest::

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.mysearchapp"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Menu(res/menu/second.xml)::

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Layout(res/layout)::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

searchable.xml(in res/xml)::

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:hint="search..."
  android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

The custom Adapter::

```
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<String> originalData = null;
        ArrayList<String> filteredData = null;

        ValueFilter valueFilter = new ValueFilter();

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mobileValues) 
 {
            this.context = context;
            this.originalData = mobileValues;
            this.filteredData = mobileValues;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return filteredData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return filteredData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return filteredData.indexOf(getItem(position));
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from mobile.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_list_item, null);

                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(originalData.get(position));

                // set image based on selected text
                // ImageView imageView = (ImageView)
                // gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

                // imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.city_image);

            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return valueFilter;
        }

        private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String filterString = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                /*
                 * if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                 */
                final ArrayList<String> lst = ImageAdapter.this.originalData;
                int count = lst.size();

                final ArrayList<String> filterList = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                String filterableString;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    filterableString = lst.get(i);

                    if ((filterableString.toUpperCase()).contains(filterString)) {

                        filterList.add(filterableString);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
                /* } *//*
                         * else { results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                         * results.values = mStringFilterList; }
                         */
                return results;

            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    }
```

And the activity::

```
    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

        // ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
        ImageAdapter myAdapter;
        ListView listView;
        // String[] dataArray = new String[] {"India","Androidhub4you", "Pakistan",
        // "Srilanka", "Nepal", "Japan"};
        private ArrayList<String> dataArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

            dataArray.add("India");
            dataArray.add("Androidhub4you");
            dataArray.add("Pakistan");
            dataArray.add("Srilanka");
            dataArray.add("Nepal");
            dataArray.add("Japan");

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataArray);
            myAdapter = new ImageAdapter(SecondActivity.this, dataArray);
            listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

                    System.out.println(arg2 + " --postion");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.second, menu);

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                    .getActionView();

            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

            SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                    myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    System.out.println("on text chnge text: " + newText);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                    myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                    System.out.println("on query submit: " + query);
                    return true;
                }
            };
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }
    }
```

Comment: define "doesn't search properly"

Comment: Well, you can just download and run my code. If i type 'ne' in search of action bar, its just showing india in listview- whereas it should be showing Nepal.

Comment: Nobody is gonna download and install your app code. You should post the **relevant** code here instead

Comment: Add some logging at the beginning and end (or various relevant points) of your filtering method to determine what comes in, what goes out and where it goes haywire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter move this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
textView.setText(originalData.get(position));
```

right before the return statement.

How the `getView` method works:

If a view is already available take that view, if it is not available make a new one. Now that the adapter has a view, load it with data.

**Full code**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // gridView = new View(context); // this line is useless, you're overwriting the variable on the next line

        // inflate new layout
        // gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_list_item, null); // wrong
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_list_item, parent, false); // right
    } else {
        // reuse previously created view
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    // set value into textview
    TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
    textView.setText(originalData.get(position));

    // set image based on selected text
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.city_image);

    // finding views all over again is not effective, google "viewholder"

    return gridView;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The correct item to load comes not from the original data set but from the filtered one. After implementing `String getItem(int)` method properly always call this method inside your `View getView(int, View, parent)`.

```
textView.setText(getItem(position));
```

Comment: I removed the textView. But its showing false(instead of the values of arraylist) in whole listView.

Comment: sorry Eugen, still the same issue.

Comment: finally change `originalData.get(position)` to `getItem(position)`. other than that I'm out of ideas

Comment: Thanks man, helped me a lot. just had to do - textView.setText(getItem(position).toString());

Comment: Option 2 would be making `getItem` return `String` instead of `Object`. I'm glad you got it working.